# GetParametersRequest returns empty result list while the response body is not empty

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

Trying to retrieve some parameters from AWS parameter store with `GetParametersRequest`. The result is success and it's possible to read the response buffer in `SetDataReceivedEvent` handler. The region and credentials are configured already on my computer and when reading the response body I can see the result in json format and also the result is success however the size of the result is 0, using the code below. How should I retrieve the result without parsing the response body?

````
#include <aws/ssm/SSMClient.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentials.h>
#include <aws/ssm/model/GetParametersByPathRequest.h>
#include <aws/ssm/model/GetParametersByPathResult.h>
#include <aws/ssm/model/GetParametersRequest.h>
#include <aws/ssm/model/GetParametersResult.h>

void getParam(const Aws::SSM::SSMClient& client)
{
    Aws::SSM::Model::GetParametersRequest request;
    request.SetNames({ "/some/config/parameter" });
    request.SetWithDecryption(true);

    request.SetWithDecryption(true);
    request.SetDataSentEventHandler([&request](const Aws::Http::HttpRequest*, long long) {
        std::cout << "Request sent:\n" << request.SerializePayload() << std::endl;
        });
    request.SetDataReceivedEventHandler([](const Aws::Http::HttpRequest*, Aws::Http::HttpResponse* resp, long long) {
        std::cout << "\nResponse body:\n" << resp->GetResponseBody().rdbuf() << std::endl;
        });
    Aws::SSM::Model::GetParametersOutcome result = client.GetParameters(request);
    if (!result.IsSuccess())
    {
        std::cout << "failed : " << result.GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "succeed" << std::endl;
        auto response = result.GetResult();
        auto params = response.GetParameters();
        std::cout << "size : " << params.size() << std::endl;
        for (const auto& r : params)
        {
            std::cout << "name : " << r.GetName() << " value : " << r.GetValue() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Trace;

    Aws::InitAPI(options);
    {
        Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration configs;
        if (configs.region.empty())
        {
            configs.region = "US_EAST_1";
        }

        Aws::SSM::SSMClient client(configs);

        getParam(client);
    }

    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);

    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the `rdbuf()` usage in event handler. I added it to see the response and it was not necessary so removing it fixed the issue.

```
request.SetDataReceivedEventHandler([](const Aws::Http::HttpRequest*, Aws::Http::HttpResponse* resp, long long) {
    std::cout << "\nResponse body:\n" << resp->GetResponseBody().rdbuf() << std::endl;
});
```